# How to set log4j config to project's dependencies?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am using `log4j2` in my project with `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=src/main/resources/log4j2.xml`.
My application loggers write logs in the format specified by the configuration file.

I have other dependencies (`sparkjava`, `hazelcast`, `mongodb`, `sql2o` etc..) that also write logs, but in different format. I would like those loggers to use my `log4j` configuration file.

How can I do it?

EDIT:

My `log4j2.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

As I understand it, every log message should be relate to the `root` logger, and thus be formatted according to my `log4j2.xml` configuration file.

Comment: can you give us your log4j2.xml, log4j2 support APIs: SLF4J, Commons Logging, Log4j-1.x and java.util.logging. So this logs are collected by log4j2. You say different format, but in the same appenders than log4j2 ?

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque I added the file

Answer (score 2):

Add the log4j 2 jars and the adapters for other logging APIs:

1. log4j-api (always)
2. log4j-core (always)
3. log4j-1.2-api
4. log4j-jcl
5. log4j-slf4j-impl (do NOT add log4j-to-slf4j)

Remove other logging implementations:

1. log4j-1.2.x
2. logback-core-*
3. logback-classic-*

Keep the facades:

1. commons-logging-*
2. slf4j-api-*